# Android Emulator Failing to Run

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, android-emulator

When I am running the Android Emulator it loads the application but does not pass the initial black screen. Eventually, the emulator closes automatically with the below message

```
"Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)".
```

How can I fix the above issue? Do let me know if anyone has any solution

[image]

[image]

Comment: Recommend you to reinstall emulator. I think emulator file was damaged. You may download on official website. It more safety

Comment: Whats your system configuration? If you have <=4GB RAM, this might occurs.

Comment: Did you try wipe emulators data? You can do it from AVD manager.

Answer (score 0):

Go to :
Tools-> SDK Manager-> Android SDK -> SDK Tools-> **Android Emulator**(if check unchecked) uninstall it and then reinstall and also check **The intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer)** same uninstall and reinstall

Comment: I tried what you suggested above but the issue still persists.

Comment: Delete the device and again create and then follow these steps.

Comment: The emulator got to the google loading screen but crashed shortly after.